# how to set fabric js to view only?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to display a previously saved drawing in Fabric.js, and then turn it into a view only, no editing mode.  Here's what I have:

```
canvas1.loadFromJSON(cavasData, canvas1.renderAll.bind(canvas1));
canvas1.isDrawingMode = false;
canvas1.deactivateAll();
canvas1.selection = false;
```

But it isn't untouchable.  Displays fine, but objects are still select-able and change-able.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When loading from `json` you should disable object selection,

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
    object.set('selectable', false);
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mq7t5n8e/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most stable way is to set `pointer-events` css property on a parent HTML Element:

```
.locked {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

To set this property from javascript:

```
let canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas-container")[0]
canvasElement.classList.add("locked")
```

To unlock canvas:

```
canvasElement.classList.remove("locked")
```

Comment: This works very well for me in my context, thanks.